# Два разных infoWindow для разных маркеров

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, infowindow

Всем привет,подскажите пожалуйста,как можно для разных групп маркеров,создающихся через

```
     Map<String, Marker> artefacts = new HashMap();
        Marker Artefact;
Artefact = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(a_lat, a_lon)) //setting position
                            .draggable(false)
                            .title(name)
                            .snippet(a_key)
                            .icon(icon)); //Adding a title
                artefacts.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), Artefact);
```

и через

```
Map<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap();
test = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.me);
                        Marker uAmarker  = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(latitude, lontitude)) //setting position
                                .draggable(false)
                                .title("Моя позиция")
                                .icon(test)); //Adding a title
                        markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), uAmarker);
```

Сделать разные infoWindow? То есть чтобы у каждой "группы" был свой дизайн и т.п

Answer (score 1):

Создайте свой класс, чтобы управлять маркерами и примените к нему **GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter**, а маркером управляйте в **getInfoContents(Marker marker)**

Например,

```
public class MapInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter{

  private Context context;
  private View myView;
  ... 

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       //получаем маркер проверяем его на что-то и строим нужный View            
       if(marker.getTitle().equals("Я")){
           myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow1, null);
       }else
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow2, null);

       return myContentsView;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if(marker.getTitle().equals("Я")){` благодаря этому направили меня на более простую мысль)Разным группам маркеров выдаю тег через `marker.setTag("TAG")` и потом делаю проверку.Без доп классов и т.д)